# MVC Partial View not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Partial  view is not rendering while passing ViewModel.. Its rendering without ViewModel.
I mean if I keep @Html.Partial("PartialClientIndex") then its rendering and when I pass ViewModel it directly going to Dispose without rendering partial view.
I'm missing something here.. could you please help in this.

Main View:

```
    <div id="PartialClient">    
        @Html.Partial("PartialClientIndex", viewModelList)                     
   </div>
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PartialClientIndex(int? SelectedGroupId)
    {
        int SkipRec = 0;
        int NextRec = 25;            
        VMClient vmclient = new VMClient();
        vmclient.IEClients = db.client.Where(cl => cl.Groups.id == SelectedGroupId).OrderBy(c => c.id).Skip(SkipRec).Take(NextRec).ToList();
        return PartialView("PartialClientIndex", vmclient);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<HostingManager.Models.VMClient>
   <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="width:25px; padding:10px;">
      Group
    </th>
    <th class="tbContent-Name">
        Client Name
    </th>
    <th class="tbContent-Name">
        Contact Person
    </th>
    <th class="tbContent-Name">
        Contact Email
    </th >        
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   @if(Model != null)        
   {
       var x = Model.Select(c=>c.IEClients).ToList();
       var y = x[0].ToList();

     //  var y = x[0]["item1"];
         foreach (var item in y) {
            <tr> 
                <td class="tbContent-Name">
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Groups.name)
                </td>      
                <td class="tbContent-Name">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contactPerson)
                </td>
                <td class="tbContent-Name">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contactPerson)
                </td>
                <td class="tbContent-Name">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contactEmail)
                </td>        
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |          
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this ?');" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
            }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: show the partial view code

Comment: I have added Partial view code @Ehsan Sajjad.. could you please advice

Comment: at first glance, you are attempting to pass a model to an `ActionResult` that is asking for an `int?`

Comment: @ethorn10 `@Html.Partial` won't call the action method, it just runs the `cshtml` file with that name

Comment: @user2254395 if it is going straight to dispose, I suspect there is an error occurring in the partial view - is `viewModelList` definitely an `IEnumerable<VMClient>`? how do you create this variable?

Comment: Can you post the code of the VMClient?

Comment: @Rhumborl - good call on the action method...I forgot that. I'd bet the `viewModelList` is either not the expected type or isn't set properly on the parent action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the variable `vmclient` that you are passing as model into your partial view is of type `VMClient`. Though your partial view is expecting the `IEnumerable<VMClient>` type.

You basically have to change the model type in your partial view to the following

```
@model HostingManager.Models.VMClient
```

and adjust the way you are assigning the `y` variable

```
var y = Model.IEClients;
```

Comment: I've updated the model type definition line - seems that I accidentally wrote IEnumerable<VMClient> from the first try )